# Django CheckBox styling

Tags: html, css, django, jinja2

I'm referring [this link](http://arthurgouveia.com/prettyCheckable/) for the styling of checkboxes.

I'm using Django Jinja Template library and here is my code

```
{%block css%}
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/prettyCheckable.css">
{%endblock%}

{% block footer %}
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/static/js/prettyCheckable.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $().ready(function(){

              $('input.myClass').prettyCheckable();

            });
        </script>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
   {% for user in users %}
       <input type="checkbox" class="myClass" value="yes" id="answer" name="answer"/>{{user.name}}<br>    
   {%endfor%}
{%endblock%}
```

My mouse pointer changes upon taking it to the user's name though it does not shows the checkbox. There are images(.png files) as well in the downloaded zip file. Now I want to ask where those files will go in my django static folder?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a label

```
   <input type="checkbox" class="myClass" value="yes" id="answer" name="answer"/><label for="answer">{{user.name}}</label><br>
```

Comment: No, it isnt happening. But, I think I have found the solution. My mouse pointer changes upon taking it to the user's name though it does not shows the checkbox. There are images as well in the downloaded zip file. Now I want to ask where those files will go in my static folder?

Comment: see the relative path in the css files and place in a similar path. If the img path is: ../img/file.png it goes in static/img. If its in the same path as css it will go in static/img. you can check chrome for 404 errors to see if they are loaded

Answer (score 0):

did you see the property of css?, if you did,  you should find the code as follow:

```
height: 30px;
width: 30px;
display: block;
float: left;
cursor: pointer;
margin: 0;
background: url('../img/sprites-sfa68604977.png');
```

and i find you link the css file in

```
     <link rel="stylesheet"href="/static/css/prettyCheckable.css">
```

so if you want to show the image, you should promise that the directory of css exists img/sprites-sfa68604977.png');

finally, i changed the style of checkbox justnow..
i used this [css checkbox](http://csscheckbox.com/)...
i hope this answer is useful to you:)